# DbUpdateException was unhandles by user code

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have searched all the equivalent answers for my problem and have found no help thus far, so posted.

I want to add multiple comments to a blog service I have and Im getting this error

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

My method throwing that exception is :

```
public int AddPost(Post newPost)
{
    context.Posts.Add(newPost);
    context.SaveChanges();
    return newPost.PostId;
}
```

Some more detailed error messages were:

> {"The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   \"FK_dbo.Posts_dbo.Users_UserId\". The conflict occurred in database
>   \"ChessDb\", table \"dbo.Users\", column 'UserId'.\r\nThe statement
>   has been terminated."}

Here is what my Blog `pocos` looks like:

```
[DisplayName("Blog ID")]
public int BlogId { get; set; }

public string Title { get; set; }

public string Content { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Author")]
public string AuthorName { get; set; }

public virtual HashSet<Post> Posts {get; set;}

public virtual User User { get; set; }

public int UserId { get; set; }
```

Im frustrated that it wont update, because I want multiple comments on one `Id`. I can **add one** fine, but I included the `hashset` of posts so I could have multiple comments.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Are you sure the UserId for the post you trying to add really exists in DB?

Comment: Why you are posting the `Blog` entity while the code and the exception are for `Post` entity? Please update your question accordingly.